# log4j2 - Automatic reload and composite configuration

Tags: java, log4j2

The automatic reload was working up until I added a second file to the `log4j.configurationFile` property. I now get this error when updating the log4j2.xml file, or rather I get the same error message twice...

```
2017-10-02 12:06:44,461 Log4j2-TF-2-ConfiguratonFileWatcher-2 ERROR No logging configuration
2017-10-02 12:06:44,462 Log4j2-TF-2-ConfiguratonFileWatcher-2 ERROR No logging configuration
```

Here's the problematic property...

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml,c:\tmp\override-log4j2.xml
```

Note, this only affects reload. Initially, the composite configuration works fine.

This is a maven project, ran in eclipse using `jetty:run` and log4j2 2.9.0.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Here's the log4j2.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration monitorInterval="5">

  <appenders>

    <console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <patternLayout pattern="%d %5p [%t] [%X{users}] (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </console>

    <rollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="myApp.log" filePattern="myApp.log">
      <patternLayout pattern="%d %5p [%t] [%X{users}] (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
      <policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10mb" />
      </policies>
      <defaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </rollingFile>

  </appenders>


  <loggers>
    <root level="warn">
      <appenderRef ref="console" />
      <appenderRef ref="rollingFile" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.mycompany" level="info" />
  </loggers>

</configuration>
```

Here's override-log4j2.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>
  <loggers>
    <root level="warn" />
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: After looking into the code it looks like a log4j2 bug. I've raised a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2068) .

Comment: Update- it has been fixed in log4j 2.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update @gaurav.

Apparently, (I've not tested) the ticket was resolved in 2.10.0.